# Why can't the JavaFx SceneBuilder find a user defined class?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-8, scenebuilder

The sample source code can be found here.
https://github.com/Shawn1874/JavaPractice/tree/master/JavaFxSandbox/ColorChooser

The program executes successfully, but I can no longer open the fxml file within SceneBuilder.  I have been experimenting with a custom class that inherits from TextField.  Netbeans clearly understands how to find the class in question because it isn't showing an error in the editor when viewing the fxml file.  I would guess that it is fairly common for SW developers to write custom controls and reference them from within SceneBuilder.  Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Did you import your jar into Scene Builder? See for instance [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36932986/3956070)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Scenebuilder that there are more classes in addition to the base JavaFX classes that it should be aware of.

To do this, click the cog icon on the right of the "library" pane, and select "JAR/FXML manager", and then add your JAR or FXML from there.